# how to pass data from ngresource factory to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory that returns a JSON object using `$resource.get` request but I cannot get some data from my ngresource factory:

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>city</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data.records">
        <td style="padding: 20px">{{records.Name}}</td>
        <td style="padding: 20px">{{records.City}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);

angular.module('myApp').controller("myCtrl",function (yourService,$scope) {

});

angular.module('myApp').

factory('yourService', ["$resource", function($resource,$scope){

    return $resource("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").get().$promise
        .then (function (data){


    });
    return data;
}]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple parameters in AngularJS $resource GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604693/multiple-parameters-in-angularjs-resource-get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your factory to

```
factory('yourService', ["$resource", function($resource, $scope) {
  return $resource("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").get().$promise
    .then(function(data) {
       return data;
    });
}]);
```

and inside your controller get the data:

```
yourService.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.records);
});
```

See [fiddle](http://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/GrvOVW?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

Your return data is not in correct place. return data in inside response.

```
  factory('yourService', ["$resource", function($resource) {
  return $resource("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").get().$promise
    .then(function(data) {
       return data;
    });
}]);
```